# MSSQL query optimization (Sub Query, Correlated sub query)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there anyway I can optimize this query? Currently it takes me half an hour to run the query below.

I have tried it as a subquery and tried adding the `Outer Apply` instead as well, but I see no improvement in performance. How would I go about improving this performance?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT invoiceno,
       dealno,
       customerno,
       vendorno,
       previous1 = (SELECT TOP 1 CASE @Tax
                                   WHEN 0 THEN ( i1.invoicetotal - i1.invoicetax )
                                   ELSE i1.invoicetotal
                                 END
                    FROM   invoiceview i1 WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE  --ii1.orderid=
                     i1.orderid = do.orderid
                     AND i1.invoiceno != i.invoiceno
                     AND i1.billingend < i.billingend
                     AND i1.status NOT IN ( 'ESTIMATE', 'VOID' )
                    ORDER  BY i1.billingend DESC),
       previousstatus1 =(SELECT TOP 1 Rtrim(i1.status)
                         FROM   invoiceview i1 WITH (NOLOCK)
                         --join invoiceitem ii1 with (nolock) on i1.invoiceid = ii1.invoiceid
                         WHERE  --ii1.orderid=
                          i1.orderid = do.orderid
                          AND i1.invoiceno != i.invoiceno
                          AND i1.billingend < i.billingend
                          AND i1.status NOT IN ( 'ESTIMATE', 'VOID' )
                         ORDER  BY i1.billingend DESC)
FROM   invoiceview iv
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dealorder do
                    ON iv.orderid = do.orderid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice i
                    ON iv.invoiceid = i.invoiceid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN deal d
                    ON d.dealid = do.dealid
/*OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(i1.status) as previousstatus1, (CASE @Tax WHEN 0 THEN (i1.invoicetotal - i1.invoicetax) ELSE i1.invoicetotal END) as previous1
      FROM invoiceview i1 with (nolock)
      WHERE i1.orderid = do.orderid and i1.invoiceno ! = i.invoiceno and i1.billingend       ) as a */
```

---

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Without the previous status, previousstatus1 query executes within 10 seconds at most.

Comment: This appears to be a financial application. Those NOLOCK hints are going to cause you some serious issues at some point. That hint is NOT a performance tool without understanding all the nuances. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: As far as optimizing this we would need a LOT more information to help. Table structures, index definitions, approx row counts, the actual execution plan from your system currently. Just tossing a query is not enough to improve the performance.

Comment: Yes I would want to see index defnitions as well as table definitions.

Comment: NOLOCK could be very dangerous

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Adding the two sub queries increases the execution amount from 10 seconds to 30 minutes. This is a vendor supported database. So even if I get a list of indexes, chances of them placing it would be slim to none. That being said, I would like some basics, I.e....is there any other way that you may know of that I do not know without jumping into indexes, table size and etc.

Comment: Something that seems small, but might be a big help.  Move the RTRIM from inside the select to outside.  Why rtrim everything inside the select when you only care about trimming the one record that spits out of the select anyway?

Comment: Ahhh smart thank you..... You are correct. Didn't notice that until now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. I was able to figure out the issue. It was the view.Once I joined with the underlying tables and actually did an outer join rather than the sub queries, I noticed a substantial difference.